VirtualBox assigning duplicate IP address to clone with Host-only Adapter
I have two VMs where one VM has Ubuntu and the other VM is a full clone of the first VM.
Both VMs have two network interfaces (NAT and Host-only). I've changed the MAC addresses on both VMs multiple times and restarted the VMs, but no matter what I do, VirtualBox keeps giving out the same IP address (192.168.56.101) to both VMs when using the Host-only network adapter.
Any idea on what's going on?

(EDIT 1): I've noticed this exact same issue now on VMWare Workstation Pro now as well!
(EDIT 2 - 15/05/2024): I just tested where I've created a new VM from scratch (not a clone). And when connecting the non-clone VM to the Host-only Adapter, it got assigned a non conflicting IP address. So, this issue appears to be related to cloned VMs.


use "bridged adapter" in vbox settins

This is normal behavior.
When you choose a network interface that is anything but bridged or NATted, to virtualbox and to that VM, there is only one device in the network, and VirtualBox will use its internal DHCP server in that network with just that one device to hand out an IP address. No matter what the mac address is, there is just one device, so the first address in the pool is always given.
These VM's are shielded from eachother anyway, so it doesn't really matter.
If you want the VM's to see eachother, either set their network card to NATted, so they both end up in the same network, and thus the DHCP server will actually see that there are 2 devices, and with different mac addresses and hostnames, they indeed will get different ip addresses.
You can also choose to set the network devices as bridged, which places these VM's in your own network. Not only can both VM's see each other, your host pc and other pc's in the network can also see them. VirtualBox will no longer use its DHCP server to hand out ip addresses, but the DHCP server of your network does, for example, your router or Domain Controller.
You always have the choice, to set the ipaddresses to manual and set one yourself. Do keep in mind that having a host-only ethernet adapter with manual ip address will not magically make both vm's see eachother.
I do wonder what your idea is of the host only apapter in conjunction with the NATted adapter. The host only doesn't really make sense in that case.

Hey @LPChip. Thanks for your reply. I have to disagree with you response. Logically, when it comes to the Host-only Adapter, it's inteded to allow the host OS to communicate directly with the guest VM. But it will not be possible to communicate to the "correct" VM if VirtualBox's DHCP server is giving out duplicate IP addresses. I just ran a test where I have two non-cloned VMs running on the Host-only adapter, and they are each properly receiving different IP addresses. I just don't understand why cloned VMs are getting duplicate IP addresses on the Host-only Adapter.

I've just added an edit with a new screenshot. Please see "EDIT 2".
